# Multiple-file referencing in TypeScript

Tags: c#, typescript

Sorry for newbie question on TypeScript.

I started the default TypeScript app on VS2015 and hit run.

I created a very simple class - clsTest with a single public number member.
I created the declaration in the Greeter class and create the reference back to the file1.ts where the clsTest is located.

I compiled it and the default application still works (the clock is ticking).

However, as soon as I add the this._obj1 = new clsTest(); (see screen shot in red box), the whole app stops working. Have I done something super obvious? I tried digging for hours without much luck.

Your help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is there any error message you get from VS?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think - the problem is in your project configuration, if it is default - the compilation result would be two separate JS files with names `app.js` (which already declared in `index.html`) and `file1.js` (I think this one you forgot to declare in `index.html`);

So, if you would like to compile your code into a single JS file you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302686/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-combine-all-typescript-files-into-one-javascri) topic

Comment: I added the <script src=test.js"></script> before the <script src="app.js"></script>   

index.html looks like:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. Missing the test.js inside the index.html. BTW, how do I see what is the actual test.js? I can't seem to find that file in my project explorer. Is there a setting that I have to enabled?